# How do I modify one JSON property using MarkLogic XSLT?

Tags: json, xslt, marklogic

I've got some JSON, an XPath, and a value. I want to replace the existing value in the JSON property pointed to by the XPath with the new value. I was thinking I could do it with XSLT, but I'm not very good at XSLT. This will be in an XQuery module.

For XML, I can do something like this:

```
let $content :=
  document {
    <class> 
      <student rollno = "393"> 
        <firstname>Dinkar</firstname> 
        <lastname>Kad</lastname> 
        <nickname>Dinkar</nickname> 
        <marks>85</marks> 
      </student> 
      <student rollno = "493"> 
        <firstname>Vaneet</firstname> 
        <lastname>Gupta</lastname> 
        <nickname>Vinni</nickname> 
        <marks>95</marks> 
      </student>
    </class>
  }
let $template := 
  <xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match = "node()|@*"> 
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="student/marks">
      <foo>bar</foo>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
return
    xdmp:xslt-eval($template, $content)
```

That properly replaces the `class/student/marks` elements with a `<foo>bar</foo>` element.

For JSON, I'm trying this:

```
let $stuff :=
  document {
    object-node {
      "SomeProperty": object-node {
        "LowProperty1":"some string", 
        "LowProperty2":"some string", 
        "LowProperty3": array-node { "some string 1", "some string 2"}
      }
    }
  }

let $target := xdmp:unpath("/EvenLowerProperty/LowestProperty1", (), $stuff)
return
  xdmp:xslt-eval(
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0"
        xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json">
      <xsl:template match="node()"> 
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="SomeProperty/LowProperty1">
        {
          map:entry("LowProperty1", "bar")
        }
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>,
    $stuff
  )
```

I want to end up with this:

```
{
  "SomeProperty": {
    "LowProperty1":"bar", 
    "LowProperty2":"some string", 
    "LowProperty3": [ "some string 1", "some string 2" ]
  }
}
```

Instead I'm getting a copy of the original. I've tried some variations, but I'm not getting any closer. Should I expect this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that MarkLogic's XSLT processor doesn't handle JSON extensions to the same degree as its XQuery processor. `<xsl:copy>` seems to be short circuited by the `object-node()` and instead of copying only the context node, behaves like `<xsl:copy-of>`, copying all descendants, which prevents the `LowProperty1` template (and any other template) from executing. You can confirm this by adding an `<xsl:message>` to the `LowProperty1` template and see that the message is never logged.

As far as I can tell, there is no idiomatic way to copy JSON nodes from within XSLT. So an alternative is to simply convert to/from `json:object` before and after transformation - and of course this could be done in XQuery (which might be preferable) before running the XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0"
    xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
    xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp">

   <xsl:template match="document-node()">
     <xsl:variable name="jsonxml" as="element()">
       <temp><xsl:sequence select="xdmp:from-json(.)"/></temp>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:variable name="result" as="element(json:object)">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$jsonxml/json:object"/>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:sequence select="xdmp:to-json(json:object($result))"/>   
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="json:entry[@key='LowProperty1']/json:value">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>bar</xsl:text>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set the [`xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml"`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xslt#id_35081) then you can use template match patterns for the JSON node types: `object-node()`, `array-node()`, `number-node()`, `boolean-node()`, `null-node()` in addition to being able to using XPath and match patterns based upon the node names, such as `SomeProperty/LowProperty1`.

Unfortunately, the `xsl:copy` performs a deep-copy that makes it difficult to transform, and there are no XSLT node constructors available for those JSON nodes.

So, transforming JSON into XML, HTML, and text is pretty easy, but in order to construct the transformed JSON that you want, you will either want to convert to/from `json:object` as @wst demonstrated, or you could cheat a little and just generate text that is JSON.

Using some base templates that match JSON nodes and generate it's JSON text output, you can then add your own specialized template to change the `SomeProperty/LowProperty1` value:

```
let $stuff :=
  document {
    object-node {
      "SomeProperty": object-node {
        "LowProperty1":"some string", 
        "LowProperty2":"some string", 
        "LowProperty3": array-node { "some string 1", "some string 2"}
      }
    }
  }

let $target := xdmp:unpath("/EvenLowerProperty/LowestProperty1", (), $stuff)
return
  xdmp:xslt-eval(
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
        xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml">

      <xsl:output method="text"/>

      <xsl:variable name="lcurly" select="'&#123;'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="rcurly" select="'&#125;'"/>

      <xsl:template match="node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="value"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="array-node()/node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="value"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="node()" mode="name">
        <xsl:if test="string(node-name(.))!=''">"<xsl:value-of select="node-name(.)"/>": </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="text()" mode="value">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()">, </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="number-node() | boolean-node()" mode="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()">, </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="object-node()" mode="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$lcurly"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rcurly"/> 
         <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="array-node()/object-node()" mode="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="$lcurly"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rcurly"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="array-node()" mode="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="'['"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="']'"/> 
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="null-node()" mode="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="'null'"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()">, </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="SomeProperty/LowProperty1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="name"/>
        <xsl:text>"bar"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()">, </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>,
    $stuff
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless MarkLogic have done something I'm not aware of to extend the standard XSLT semantics, this isn't going to work. Match patterns like `SomeProperty/LowProperty1` can't be used to address parts of a map/array tree. You can match things in such a tree, but it's not very useful because the match can't be context-sensitive: given a map or array, you can't find out where it is or how you got there.

You might find it useful to read my XML Prague 2016 paper on transforming JSON using XSLT 3.0: http://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2016mhk.pdf

The standard approach to transforming XML using XSLT template matching doesn't translate well to JSON, the underlying reason being that the map/array structures used to represent JSON don't have "node identity" or upwards navigation (parent pointers). In the examples in my paper I generally found that the easiest way of doing this kind of transformation was to convert the structure to XML, transform the XML, and then convert back -- though there are other approaches that you might consider.

I've been trying to come up with a design for higher-order extension functions to make this kind of task easier. I don't think I have ideal solutions yet.

Comment: MarkLogic hasn't really extended the semantics of XSLT, but rather interprets JSON as a tree of nodes very similar to XML. Instead of elements, and attributes, it consists of object-node, array-node, number-node, null-node, and text. It makes using XPath and XSLT on JSON possible, though with a few quirks..

Answer (score 2):

I was inspired by @MadsHansen's discovery of the `xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml"` option to create a more idiomatic version of my other answer. Using this XSLT, you maintain the ability to create templates using MarkLogic JSON XPath extensions (i.e.: `match="SomeProperty/LowProperty1"`).

The difference here is that instead of converting to `json:object` XML wholesale at the beginning, native JSON objects are maintained initially and only converted to `json:object` during the transformation. Then at the end, everything is converted back to native. The only downside is that you need to either use `json:object` XML when constructing new JSON inside templates, or wrap the native constructors in `xdmp:from-json()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0"
    xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
    xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml">

    <!-- XML -->
    <xsl:template match="SomeProperty/LowProperty1">
      <xsl:text>bar</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>     

    <!-- Native JSON syntax -->
    <xsl:template match="SomeProperty/LowProperty2">
      {xdmp:from-json(
        object-node { "foo" : "bar" }
      )}
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- Conversion handling -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="result" as="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="namespace-uri-from-QName($result/node-name(.)) = 'http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json'">
          <xsl:sequence select="xdmp:to-json(json:object($result))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity templates below -->

    <xsl:template name="json:value">
      <xsl:variable name="result" as="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:variable>        
      <json:value>                       
        <xsl:if test=". instance of number-node()">
          <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">
            <xsl:value-of select="xs:QName('xs:integer')"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
      </json:value>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object-node()"> 
      <json:object>
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
          <json:entry key="{{ name(.) }}">
            <xsl:call-template name="json:value"/>
          </json:entry>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </json:object>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="array-node()"> 
      <json:array>        
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
          <xsl:call-template name="json:value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </json:array>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="number-node()">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" priority="-1">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note that the native JSON syntax only works when used with `xdmp:xslt-eval` - the native syntax is evaluated in XQuery and converted to `json:object` XML before the XSLT is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @wst that there is something odd with `xsl:copy`. It indeed seems to do a copy-of, rather than recurse into a object-node, at least in ML9. Haven't tested with ML10 yet.

The `xdmp:dialect` mentioned by @mads-hansen is definitely useful here, though it is not necessary to convert the entire tree to XML notation while copying, and back to JSON in the end. You can also use the internal json:object type, and convert that at shallow level where needed.

This show how to replace the usual identity transform with something that works for JSON:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $stuff :=
  document {
    object-node {
      "SomeProperty": object-node {
        "LowProperty1":"some string", 
        "LowProperty2":"some string", 
        "LowProperty3": array-node { "some string 1", "some string 2"}
      }
    }
  }

let $target := xdmp:unpath("/EvenLowerProperty/LowestProperty1", (), $stuff)
return
  xdmp:xslt-eval(
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0" xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml"
        xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json">

      <xsl:template match="object-node()">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="json:object()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
          <xsl:variable name="contents" as="item()*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:sequence select="map:put($this, name(.), $contents)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:sequence select="xdmp:to-json($this)"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="array-node()">
        <xsl:variable name="contents" as="item()*">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="json:to-array($contents)"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="SomeProperty/LowProperty1">
        <xsl:text>foo</xsl:text>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>,
    $stuff
  )
```

HTH!